# Infinispan Hibernate search exception: org.hibernate.hql.ParsingException: HQLLUCN000003

Tags: hibernate-search, infinispan

Using Infinispan 6.0

Hi I have setup infinispan in embeded cache mode and I'm able to write to the cahce. Now I'm attempting to add indexing and it seems to all load properly but when I try to query my cache I get the following exception...

org.hibernate.hql.ParsingException: HQLLUCN000003: No queries can be applied to property ABC in type com.xxx.model.MyModel since the property is analyzed.

And I can't seem to find info on this error on google.

Infinispan config...

```
<namedCache name="XYZ">
    <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="30000000" />
    <indexing enabled="true" indexLocalOnly="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="default.directory_provider" value="ram" />
        </properties>
    </indexing>
</namedCache>
```

The model is this...

```
@Indexed
public class MyModel implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3764014970811943408L;

    Integer key;
    @Field
    @Field
    String ABC;
}
```

My query is this...

```
Query query = qf.from(MyModel.class)
    .maxResults(20000)
    .having("ABC")
    .toBuilder().build();
```

The log output seems ok

```
DEBUG org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil - Object name org.infinispan:type=Cache,name="__cluster_registry_cache__(local)",manager="DefaultCacheManager",component=Cache already registered
INFO  o.i.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration - ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
DEBUG org.infinispan.CacheImpl - Started cache __cluster_registry_cache__ on null
DEBUG o.i.interceptors.InterceptorChain - Interceptor chain size: 7
DEBUG o.i.interceptors.InterceptorChain - Interceptor chain is:
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.query.backend.LocalQueryInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
DEBUG org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil - Object name org.infinispan:type=Cache,name="XYZ(local)",manager="DefaultCacheManager",component=Cache already registered
INFO  o.i.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration - ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
DEBUG org.infinispan.CacheImpl - Started cache XYZ on null
```

And then when I try to query...

```
WARN  o.h.search.impl.ConfigContext - HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified, using LUCENE_CURRENT.
DEBUG o.h.s.b.impl.lucene.WorkspaceFactory - Starting workspace for index com.xxx.model.Transaction using an exclusive index strategy
DEBUG o.h.s.e.s.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity - Field selection in projections is set to true for entity com.xxx.model.MyModel.
org.hibernate.hql.ParsingException: HQLLUCN000003: No queries can be applied to property ABC in type com.xxx.model.MyModel since the property is analyzed.
    at org.hibernate.hql.lucene.internal.ClassBasedLuceneQueryResolverDelegate.normalizeProperty(ClassBasedLuceneQueryResolverDelegate.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.lucene.internal.ClassBasedLuceneQueryResolverDelegate.normalizePropertyPathTerminus(ClassBasedLuceneQueryResolverDelegate.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.pathedPropertyReference(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:13086)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.propertyReferencePath(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:12917)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.valueExpressionPrimary(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:7950)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.valueExpression(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:7483)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.rowValueConstructor(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:6377)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.predicate(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:5213)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4858)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.searchCondition(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.whereClause(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:2348)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.querySpec(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:2203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.queryExpression(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:2106)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.queryStatement(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:1745)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.queryStatementSet(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:1658)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.origin.hql.resolve.GeneratedHQLResolver.statement(GeneratedHQLResolver.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.spi.QueryResolverProcessor.process(QueryResolverProcessor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.hql.QueryParser.parseQuery(QueryParser.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.query.dsl.embedded.impl.EmbeddedLuceneQueryBuilder.build(EmbeddedLuceneQueryBuilder.java:51)
    at org.infinispan.query.dsl.embedded.impl.EmbeddedLuceneQueryBuilder.build(EmbeddedLuceneQueryBuilder.java:27)
    at com.xxx.vertx.Inifini.handle(Inifini.java:97)
    at com.xxx.vertx.Inifini.handle(Inifini.java:1)
    at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus$11.run(DefaultEventBus.java:929)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is suggesting, for this kind of query you need a non-analyzed field.
You get it by altering your model:

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;

@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
String ABC;
```

Note that if you where needing to have this field Analyzed - as it's a requirement for other more advanced queries - you could use the annotation in its plural form *@Fields* to list multiple fields with different options.

Comment: So if I'm doing straigh equals queries Analyze = NO should even be a performance boost right? Since there no extra analyzing to do?

Comment: It would also be nice to know why it threw the error on default config.